# Wait not working in Firefox browser (Webdriver selenium 2.0 +Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using WebDriver(Eclipse -Java) to automate a Registration page. On clicking the 'Register' button, a 'success message' is displayed and need to validate the same.

I can do this successfully in IE8. But not able to validate the same in Firefox. I have tried different waits
1. d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

1. WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ElmId"));
2. Wait wait = new FluentWait wait = new FluentWait(d1).withTimeout(60, SECONDS);
   wait.until(new Function()
                   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(d1.findElement(By.id("elementid"))));

Has anyone faced similar issues? Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with other conditions types? Or you could also try writing your own by overriding the apply method. I had few cases when using the provided conditions was not enough. Only after using my own version of apply method it was successfull.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(timeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(pollingInterval,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    return wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {

        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
            List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(By.className(someClassName));
            for (WebElement webElement : findElements) {
                if (webElement.getText().equals(string)) {
                    return webElement;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
```

e. g. something like this was pretty helpful few times.

Answer (score 0):

This 'success message' after clicking a button: is it displayed with ajax/javascript or do you reload a page?

In case you're doing it with js it may be sometimes impossible to verify the message with WebDriver command and you will need to use js for verification too. Something like:

```
Object successMessage = null;
int counter = 0;

    while ((successMessage == null) && counter < 5)
    {
        try
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('yourId')");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            counter +=1;
        }
    }

    if (successMessage != null) //would be better to use some assertion instead of conditional statement
    {
        //OK
    }
    else
    {
        //throw exception
    }
```

The while loop is ugly way for pseudo-wait functionality. You may as well remove it if you don't need to wait for element.

The alternative could be

```
Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.body.innerHtml"); 
String html = result.toString();
```

and then parsing html manually.